# cp and rm not recognized as internal or external command windows 10

Tags: javascript, command-line, command

How can I deal with this, How do i get the cp and rm commands to run on windows?

```
"copy:hosting": "cp -r ./dist/mysite/* ./public && rm ./public/index.html",
```

Or if there's an equivalent of rewriting the above to work in windows?

Comment: the Windows command line is not Unix. To use Unix commands, you have to install additional software. The equivalent Windows commands are [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) and [del](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html). see [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) for a complete list of Windows Command Line commands.

Answer (score 3):

[download Git-Bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

This is a command prompt that accepts Linux Commands, so you can use Linux commands on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

If you use visual studio code, install git (with GitBash) and change in VSC settings terminal options on use external terminal and set External: Windows Exec link on git-bash.exe

Comment: That's correct. Also, remember to terminate the current terminal and switch to Git Bash.